# Spring Cache Manager add new cache without anotations

Tags: java, spring, ehcache

I can get items out of the cache manager by using

```
cachemanager.getCache("cachename").get(cacheKey)
```

How do I add a new cache via the cache manager? There appears to be only `getCache()` and `getCacheNames()`.

There is `getCache("newcachename").put(cacheKey)` but that fails as `"newcachename"` doesn't exist.

Comment: I should note that I can cache items with :-

@Cacheable(value="requestLocationsSearch", key="#request.requestId")

And it works fine. Basically I want a way to add to the cache without the use of and annotation.

Answer (score 1):

Sorted, my fault. I didnt add the new cache details to the ehcache.xml file.

`<cache name="newcachename" maxElementsInMemory="10000"
           eternal="false" timeToIdleSeconds="300" timeToLiveSeconds="300"
           overflowToDisk="false" diskPersistent="false"/>`

Once I added this I could use

`getCache("newcachename").put(cacheKey, "value to cache")`

Thanks all for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you configuration looks like so I can't give a more detailed explanation, but I have successfully used multiple caches using Spring's `CompositeCacheManager`

Answer (score 0):

```
  <set>
    <bean class="org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCacheFactoryBean" p:name="newcachename" />
  </set>
```

Have you set  up this cache for this cacheName in the configurations?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Another developer who is much more experienced with spring, setup the config for this app. It class based config and the cacheManager used appears to be `org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager;`

I cant find any mention of `ConcurrentMapCacheFactoryBean` in the app.